# Request to virtual ip is not forwarding while trying IP Failover using keepalived on centos 7

Tags: iptables, ip, testing, failover

I am trying to test IP failover using keepalived on centos 7. I have three instances of centos 7 installed on my vm. So I have 3 servers. I am trying to run keepalived on two of them, 3rd centos will be acting as a real server where request will be forwarded to.
The configuration of the keepalived is given at the end. In conf file 192.168.10.40 is the ip address of the real server. On real server I just have a small nodejs server running which replies as success when request is sent. When I sent request to nodejs server directly at 192.168.10.40:3869. It replies, But when I try to reach it using virtual ip 192.168.10.100 and port 3869, It does not reply. Although keepalived on both servers is working fine.

On master server

```
Vrrp_instance_pi1 {
state MASTER
    interface enp0s8
    virtual_router_id 102
    priority 101
    authentication {
        auth_type PASS
        auth_pass 1234
    }
    virtual_ipaddress {
        192.168.10.100/24
    }
}
virtual_server 192.168.10.100 3869 {
    delay_loop 10
    lb_algo rr
    lb_kind DR
    persistence_timeout 9600


    real_server 192.168.10.40 3869 {
        weight 1
        TCP_CHECK {
        connect_timeout 20
        connect_port    80
        }
    }
                                                                                         
}
```

On backup server

```
Vrrp_instance_pi1 {
state BACKUP
    interface enp0s8
    virtual_router_id 102
    priority 99
    authentication {
        auth_type PASS
        auth_pass 1234
    }
    virtual_ipaddress {
        192.168.10.100/24
    }
}
virtual_server 192.168.10.100 3869 {
    delay_loop 10
    lb_algo rr
    lb_kind DR
    persistence_timeout 9600


    real_server 192.168.10.40 3869 {
        weight 1
        TCP_CHECK {
        connect_timeout 20
        connect_port    80
        }
    }
                                                                                         
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the NodeJS server, redefine the default route, to point to the floating IP `192.168.10.100`

```
$ sudo ip route del 0/0
$ sudo route add default gw 192.168.10.100
```

On both routers, make some NAT rules:

```
$ sudo iptables -t nat -F
$ sudo iptables -t mangle -F
$ sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.10.0/24 -j SNAT --to 192.168.10.100
$ sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 192.168.10.100 -p tcp --dport 3869 -j DNAT --to 192.168.10.40
```

Comment: works fine, thanks, solution is up-voted. But my reputation is low. So not displaying.

Comment: @MuhammadSaleem Thanks for the upvote. Accepted